# Basic authentication pop box Chrome Selenium-webdriver in Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, automation, capybara

I have seen this asked a few times and I have come across an annoying situation.

I have to test a webpage which has an authentication box appear on the landing page needing a username and password. I can't inspect this element so I gain access via the usual 'https://username:password@url.com' to gain access.

When I get passed the authentication, the website does not load any css. It's all user agent only and I get quite a lot of errors.  A project requirement is that I must go through Chrome (lame I know) but this is causing a lot of problems. This only happens in Chrome. Accessing the website manually does not have this issue.

Is there anything I can do about this? So far I've not managed to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'sikuli' application. You can go through that time with sikuli. It also integrates into Ruby. I am living this way. It's works.

Comment: Sikuli, I've not heard of this before. Is it a gem?

Comment: No, a test tool. For example, to click on the windows window or something on the desktop. When I do web testing, the windows window opens and I pass this stage through sikuli.